# nil response object in Rails 5.2, RSpec-Rails 3.7 spec for GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rack-test

I've been heads down in this and feel like I'm probably making a simple mistake, but I haven't been able to find any information on this problem.

I have some request specs for Rails 5 and, when I test for a redirect--but not for a rendered template--I get an error, `undefined method 'response_code' for nil:NilClass`. The reason for this seems to be that `@response` is `nil` when the matcher is called (inside ActionDispatch::Assertions::ResponseAssertions code, not in my code). I am able to use cURL to make a request to the API and it returns a response as expected. The point where the error is returned is here (this is the ActionDispatch code):

```
def generate_response_message(expected, actual = @response.response_code)
  "Expected response to be a <#{code_with_name(expected)}>,"\
  " but was a <#{code_with_name(actual)}>"
  .dup.concat(location_if_redirected).concat(response_body_if_short)
end
```

Notice the first line, where the default value of the `actual` param is set to `@response.response_code`.

Here's my test code:

```
RSpec.describe "Admin registrations", type: :request do
  describe "new sign-up" do
    subject { get new_admin_registration_path }

    it "redirects to home" do
       expect(subject).to redirect_to(new_admin_session_path)
    end
  end
end
```

The relevant lines in the test log are:

```
Started GET "/admins/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-05 10:44:05 -0700
Processing by Admins::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Redirected to http://example.org/admins/sign_in
Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Interestingly, when I use byebug to check the value of `subject`, it does return a Rack::MockResponse object, so this is somehow not getting passed through.

Comment: hmm that spec looks fine.  any logs to share?  also, what happens if you do `get 'somepath/someresource'` instead

Comment: `get "somepath/someresource"` gives me a routing error. I didn't see anything out of the ordinary in the logs but I'll add what there is to the question.

Comment: sorry, i meant instead of using a path helper like you're doing, whatever the string equiv of `new_admin_registration_path` is.

Comment: Oh! I tried that, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you've probably already solved this, but for anyone else who might stumble upon this, we ran into the same thing (`response` not being assigned after a request way made - either `get` or `post`, didn't try other methods, but assume they would all be the same). Existing request specs that had been working all started failing.

The culprit in our case was tracked down to a module that was required in `rails_helper.rb`, and added to rspec's `config.include` list:

```
config.include ApiHelper, type: request
```

Inside `AppHelper` was the root cause:

```
include Rack::Test::Methods
```

Commenting that line out (and ultimately for us, removing the entire helper as it wasn't really needed) restored the request specs to their previous, and working, state.

**tl;dr:**

Make sure you're not including `Rack::Test::Methods` in `config.include` for your rspec config inadvertently.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! I did solve this, in a manner of speaking, but it was by monkey patching something, so this is a much more satisfactory solution.

Comment: This was exactly my problem too.  I added `Rack::Test::Methods` to a spec in order to test uploading a CSV, but then I spent the next half hour scratching my head as to way everything worked, but the `response` object was nil.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty dumb on my part but I bet someone else or myself is going to do this by accident.

If `type: :request` is already set in your top block, also make sure you're not accidentally overriding the `response` variable in your block.

Take my dumb self's example as a warning:

```rb
let(:response) { }

it 'overrides rspec\'s own dediciated response variable' do
   get your_route_here_path
   expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
end
```

results in something like:

`Error: nil doesn't have property 'status'`

That's because the `let(:response)` is actually overriding rspec's own internal `response`.

Just something to keep in mind, you'll probably never screw up like this but just in case.